# perl novice, need assistance with handling file script

Tags: perl

Very new to Perl. Running Perl on Padre and Windows 10 OS.

The script from my book is written for Unix.  I don't know how to correct it so that it works with Windows.

Here is the script as written in my book (FOR UNIX):

```
use warnings;
#write to a file with a filehandle. Sriptname: file.handle
my $file="/home/jody/ellie/perl/newfile";
open(my $fh, ">", $file) || die "Can't open newfile: $!\n";

print $fh "hello world.\n";
print $fh "hello world again.\n";
```

At the command line

```
$perl file.handle
$cat newfile
```

the output should be looking like this:

```
hello world. 
hello world again.
```

I made the following changes but with no success

```
use warnings;
#Write to a file with a filehandle. Scriptname: file.handle
my $file='C:\newfile.txt';
open (my $fh, ">", $file) || die "Can't open newfile: $!\n";

print $fh "hello world.\n";
print $fh "hello world again.\n";
```

When I run script I get the following output:

```
can't open newfile: permission denied**
```

When I run the script with debug I get the following information:

```
uncaught exception for user code 
can't open newfile: permission denied
at handlingfiles.pl line 5
press any key to continue
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does your user have the permission to write to the `C:\ ` folder?

Answer (score 0):

As @choroba mentioned in a comment, `C:\newfile.txt` will [try to] write to the Windows root directory (e.g. `C:\`). So, you probably want just `newfile.txt`.

**Cygwin:** If you're using the `perl` that comes with `cygwin`, you can probably use `/home/jody/newfile.txt` as this perl supports the POSIX file syntax. If you installed `cygwin` at (e.g.) `D:\cygwin`, then the `/home` directory will end up in `D:cygwin\home`. Note you do `ls /home` to see what users have been defined.

Otherwise, if you want a full path, what is the full path for your `.pl` script. Obviously, you could write to that directory.

*Side note:* I've been writing perl for many years and on those rare occasions when I do use it on Windows, I vastly prefer using the cygwin version [that also has many scripts, tools, etc. and functions like a POSIX environment]. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Perl is asked to open the file for writing, so that is what it does. On Windows, normal users cannot write to the root directory of a drive, and Windows rejects its request. Try something like `C:\Users\User\My Documents\newfile.txt`.